# Can I pass a lambda to a constexpr constructor?

Tags: c++

I have this constexpr class:

```
class ParamType {
public:
    constexpr ParamType(std::string_view name, std::string_view uuid,
            float minVal, float maxVal, float defVal,
            std::function<void(float)> onValue) :
            kName(name),
            kMinVal(minVal),
            kMaxVal(maxVal),
            kDefVal(defVal),
            uuid(uuid){}

    constexpr ParamType(const ParamType &other) = delete;

    ParamType &operator=(const ParamType &other) = delete;

    constexpr ParamType(ParamType &&other) = default;

    constexpr ParamType &operator=(ParamType &&other) = delete;

    const std::string_view kName;
    const std::string_view uuid;
    const float kMinVal, kMaxVal, kDefVal;
};
```

I'm trying to add `std::function<void(float)> onValue`. As far as I understand, a lambda should be assignable to a constexpr class. Why I cannot put it there?

It says:

```
Constexpr constructor's 6th parameter type 'std::function<void (float)>' is not a literal type 'function<void (float)>' is not literal because it is not an aggregate and has no constexpr constructors other than copy or move constructors
```

I want to store this lambda into `ParamType`

Comment: `ParamType` doesn't even do anything with the last constructor parameter...   But "a lambda should be assignable to a `constexpr` class" can be true simultaneously with "`std::function` is not `constexpr`"  You may have to use something other than `std::function` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with lambdas.  The actual error message from clang - just compiling your class, without even trying to instantiate it - is:

> 'function<void (float)>' is not literal because it is not an aggregate and has no constexpr constructors other than copy or move constructors

which is pretty much self-explanatory.

You can work around this if it's OK for `onValue` to be a plain-old function pointer.  The following code compiles correctly (but would not work with a capturing lambda):

```
#include <string>

class ParamType {
public:
    constexpr ParamType(std::string_view name, std::string_view uuid,
            float minVal, float maxVal, float defVal,
            void (* onValue) (float)) :
            kName(name),
            kMinVal(minVal),
            kMaxVal(maxVal),
            kDefVal(defVal),
            uuid(uuid) { }

    const std::string_view kName;
    const float kMinVal, kMaxVal, kDefVal;
    const std::string_view uuid;
};

int main()
{
    ParamType pt ("name", "uuid", 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, [] (float f) { });
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DC4a9B2t62W6wBr8)